# Python convert unicode with ''.join (TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found)

Tags: python, unicode, hex

I'm using python 2.7.9 to convert unicode hex to unicode text and I got stuck on following code:

```
text = '0421'
converted_text = ''.join([chr(int(''.join(c), 16)) for c in zip(text[0::4], text[1::4], text[2::4], text[3::4])])
print converted_text

ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```

When I remove chr():

```
converted_text = ''.join([int(''.join(c), 16) for c in zip(text[0::4], text[1::4], text[2::4], text[3::4])])

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

If I try other text like '00DD' it works fine.
Any idea what's problem in my code?

Comment: Try using `str(...)` instead of `chr(...)`.

Comment: Actually `str(int(text, 16))` gives the same result.

Comment: You can use the string method `.decode`. In your case you would do `text.decode('hex')`

Comment: str() doesn't help, cause chr() covert decimal to unicode character in format '\x  '.

Comment: text.decode('hex') solved my problem, in that case I don't need ' '.join(....). Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK `\x' notation appears for control sequences and that have no visual representation. This explains why you have only problems with some texts when hex decoding. You can read more about it here: http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~rstephen/courses/UQI108S1/week3/lecture.html

Comment: I just check again '0421' must be 'C', but I get this '!'. a=text.decode('hex') then I print: print a.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8') I get this '!'

Comment: Thanks, i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need unicode character then solution is to use [unichr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) instead of chr().